# Refactoring class to struct

Tags: c#, visual-studio, struct, refactoring, resharper

I have a codebase that has a framework / domain type used in many places. This type is currently a class, but I would like to change it to struct since it meets struct usage recommendations ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and is a value sematically.

Is there any way I could automate this refactoring to avoid potential errors of value vs reference type usage?

Do I need to check everything manually?

PS: I am not sure immutability would solve every potential issue, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Making your struct immutable would at least break the compilation for every line you must have a deeper look at. Typically: A member assignation.

Comment: make sure you have good unit tests.

Comment: @DanielA.White - unit testing is effectively checking everything manually (if we forget about other benefits of course).

Comment: Do you have any reference equality checks used against it, or did you already overload the various equality methods/operators to do value checking instead?

Comment: If your struct is immutable, the only source of error that you could not see at compile time would be the equality comparision (==, != and .Equals()), which could have different results (class : reference comparision, struct : members comparision)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - at the moment it's just a straightforward class with several read-write properties, no overloads.

Comment: @krimog - I think this makes sense: make immutable, check equality comparisons, fix compiler errors, make mutable again if needed.

Comment: I think the answer is in the comments (unless there is an automated extension for Visual Studio or ReSharper as well). Should this question be closed?